# Rebooting on wake-up from suspend on Dell 5510 with Xubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, suspend, dell

I have a Dell 5510 with a fairly fresh install of Xubuntu, I have done a dist-upgrade since installing, but I don't believe resuming from suspend has ever worked consistently. If I suspend and resume with power plugged in then it always works fine, however if I suspend with power and then remove it, or suspend without power and then plug it in, or without power at all then it always reboots when waking up. I have tried:

- Updated the bios to 1.4 per dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/precision-m5510-workstation/drivers
- Tried changing /etc/default/grub to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_sleep=nonvs"
- Tried the fixbacklight script from here: askubuntu.com/questions/820955/blank-screen-after-resume-dell-m5510-ubuntu-16-04
- Tried just making sure brightness was up all the way before suspending
- Tried nvidia and the intel microcode
- Originally had displaylink installed and completely removed that

Here are some of the issues I now see in /var/log/syslogd when the system is going to sleep:

(I don't think this one matters because it is all over the log)

```
Oct 19 18:23:20 dusseldorf org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[1463]: ** (process:7800): WARNING **: Couldn't create directory monitor on smb://x-gnome-default-workgroup/. Error: The specified location is not mounted
```

(I wouldn't think this would break suspend)

```
Oct 19 18:23:25 dusseldorf dhclient[10861]: receive_packet failed on enxd481d7504b08: Network is down
```

(Maybe?)
    Oct 19 18:23:25 dusseldorf kernel: [ 8281.352711] xhci_hcd 0000:3e:00.0: Host halt failed, -19
    Oct 19 18:23:25 dusseldorf kernel: [ 8281.352740] xhci_hcd 0000:3e:00.0: Host not accessible, reset failed.

```
Oct 19 18:23:25 dusseldorf NetworkManager[891]: <error> [1508451805.5517] platform-linux: do-change-link[4]: failure changing link: failure 19 (No such device)
Oct 19 18:23:25 dusseldorf NetworkManager[891]: <warn>  [1508451805.5518] device (enxd481d7504b08): failed to disable userspace IPv6LL address handling

Oct 19 18:23:30 dusseldorf systemd-sleep[11638]: /lib/systemd/system-sleep/wpasupplicant failed with error code 254.
```

Here are some of the issues I see in the log when trying to resume:

```
Oct 20 10:21:04 dusseldorf ureadahead[299]: ureadahead:/lib/udev/rules.d/71-nvidia.rules: No such file or directory
...
Oct 20 10:21:04 dusseldorf ureadahead[299]: ureadahead:/lib/systemd/system/nvidia-persistenced.service: No such file or directory
...
Oct 20 10:21:04 dusseldorf ureadahead[299]: ureadahead:/lib/modules/4.10.0-37-generic/updates/dkms/nvidia_375_modeset.ko: No such file or directory
Oct 20 10:21:04 dusseldorf rsyslogd-2039: Could not open output pipe '/dev/xconsole':: No such file or directory [v8.16.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2039 ]
Oct 20 10:21:04 dusseldorf ureadahead[299]: ureadahead:/lib/modules/4.10.0-37-generic/updates/dkms/nvidia_375.ko: No such file or directory
Oct 20 10:21:04 dusseldorf ureadahead[299]: ureadahead:/lib/modules/4.10.0-37-generic/updates/dkms/nvidia_375_drm.ko: No such file or directory
Oct 20 10:21:04 dusseldorf ureadahead[299]: ureadahead:/lib/modules/4.10.0-37-generic/updates/dkms/nvidia_375_uvm.ko: No such file or directory
...
Oct 20 10:21:04 dusseldorf ureadahead[299]: ureadahead:/sbin/create-uvm-dev-node: No such file or directory
Oct 20 10:21:04 dusseldorf rsyslogd-2007: action 'action 10' suspended, next retry is Fri Oct 20 10:21:34 2017 [v8.16.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
Oct 20 10:21:04 dusseldorf ureadahead[299]: ureadahead:/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.ntpd: No such file or directory
Oct 20 10:21:04 dusseldorf ureadahead[299]: ureadahead:/etc/apparmor.d/tunables/ntpd: No such file or directory
Oct 20 10:21:04 dusseldorf ureadahead[299]: ureadahead:/etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.ntpd: No such file or directory
Oct 20 10:21:04 dusseldorf systemd[1]: Created slice system-systemd\x2dbacklight.slice.
```

And the very last line of the resume before it reboots is:

```
Oct 20 10:21:04 dusseldorf systemd[1]: Starting Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:intel_backlight...
```

Please let me know if you have any suggestions of what to try and how to troubleshoot this. Thanks.

Comment: I have tried the nvidia drivers as well as the processor microcode from Intel, as well as adding acpi_osi="Linux" to grub, but it did not matter.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. According to [Dell XPS 15 (9550) rebooting after suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/871950/dell-xps-15-9550-rebooting-after-suspend), I tried to do a full shutdown and to restart. It seems that the problem disappeared after that.

Comment: I did that, it was short lived. I have resorted to blocking S3 suspend state in the BIOS power settings so it will now suspend half way, and saves  battery more than not suspending at all, but definitely not as good as a full suspend. Pretty disappointing considering Dell actually sold this laptop with Ubuntu so you would hope they would support it going forward.