# Laptop started crashing on resume, but only on battery

Tags: suspend, power-management, 19.04, xps

I have a Dell XPS 13 9350 model running ubuntu 19.04. As of the last few days, the system has become unable to resume from suspend - after a few seconds of the screen being blank, it appears to do a cold boot i.e. shows the Dell logo, starts Ubuntu and then displays the login screen.

This happens regardless of how the system is suspended (i.e. closing the lid, using the GUI power menu, `systemctl suspend` or `sudo pm-suspend`), but only happens if the system is on battery power when it is suspended or resumed, or if the power is unplugged while it's asleep. If it stays plugged in throughout, resuming works normally.

I've had this problem before some time ago, and it was magically fixed by a kernel update. So I initially suspected a regression, but have tried several older kernels (currently running 5.0.0-27, oldest I tried was 4.13.0) and all had the same problem. I also have the `tlp` power-saving package installed which I thought might be a potential culprit, but disabling that didn't help either. The laptop otherwise runs fine on battery power, so I don't think it's a hardware issue.

I've not been able to find anything helpful in the logs, `/var/log/syslog` shows a "system suspended successfully" message and then the normal cold-boot messages from after the crash. Using `pm-suspend` does produce an error report in `/var/crash` which I can post if it's likely to be informative, but again it just seems to be showing that the suspend happened successfully and then nothing after that.

I did experience a system lock-up requiring a hard shutdown (i.e. holding the power button) while the laptop was plugged into a Thunderbolt dock around the time I first noticed the issue, so wasn't sure whether that might've screwed something up. It seemed unlikely that this would persist through reboots, but if anyone can suggest a way to troubleshoot that or any other potential cause it'd be much appreciated, cheers.

edit 14/01/20: sorry I never gave an update, the resolution is somewhat unsatisfying though. The problem went away of its own accord after doing a complete cold-start, i.e. letting the battery run down completely before plugging back in and booting the system. I'm not entirely clear on why that would help, but I've not had the issue reoccur since.

edit 26/11/20: Suddenly the problem began occurring again, on the same system now running 20.10. I found [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1038585/992405) suggesting that the embedded firmware controller is the culprit - some sort of transient error puts it in an invalid state which renders the system unable to recover from a suspend. Performing a cold start as I tried before resets the controller, restoring the normal behaviour. (note that running down the battery is not required, the system just needs to be powered off and then AC power-cycled)

This fixed the problem this time as well, so in case anyone still finds this post, this appears to be a reliable fix.

Comment: Likely, the battery is old, and when you put a large load on it, its voltage output dips below what the PC needs. To test that, 1) go into a dark room. Dial the laptop screen brightness down as far as you can practically and still see, then retry. 2) Connect an external monitor and turn off the internal screen. Please then click [edit] and let us know the results. Please don't use Add Comment; help us help you by using [edit].

Answer (score 4):

I have been having a similar problem mid-December with my Precision 7530. I could suspend my computer plugged in or running on battery, but I could not resume while running on battery.

I have tried stock Ubuntu 18.04.x, and Pop! OS 18.04 and 19.10. All were running variants of kernel 5.3.x, although Pop! OS builds their own kernel. BIOS upgraded to 0.1.12.1, the latest version at this time per Dell's website and firmware-manager. The computer is using my NVidia GPU, although the problem still happens with Intel graphics. No extra flags added my kernel parameters in `/etc/default/grub`.

I was clued into a solution by reinstalling my OS, and suspend/resume worked fine, until I installed updates. One of the updates is the `intel-microcode` package.

Rolling back `intel-microcode` from `3.20191115.1ubuntu018.04.2` to `3.20180312.0~ubuntu18.04.1`, and `apt-mark hold intel-microcode` seems to have fixed the problem for now.

On a related note, my loaner Dell Precision 5520 with similar hardware specs running an up-to-date version of Pop! OS 18.04 does not have this problem.

Comment: I have the same problem on my Dell Precision 7530 as well.  I am running Fedora 31.  Kernel versions up to 5.3.7 seem to work fine.  Kernels above 5.3.7 fail.

I wonder if this is relevant:  https://linuxreviews.org/Linux_Kernel_5.5_Will_Not_Fix_The_Frequent_Intel_GPU_Hangs_In_Recent_Kernels

Comment: Same issue, same laptop, openSUSE Tumbleweed with `5.8.0-1-default` kernel

Comment: I've tried every intel-microcode update, but with no luck.I keep returning to 3.2018. Unrelated, but given that Dell removed TrackPoint as a keyboard option if favor of a bigger trackpad, I will probably go for a P15 as my next upgrade if Lenovo comes up with a dock like the TB19.

Comment: The same issue started after I updated the BIOS of my Precision 7530 to 0.1.12. Reverting to the version of intel-microcode you mentioned solved my problem. Thanks !!

Comment: firmware 1.14.4 seems to be compatible with newer microcode versions, specifically 
`intel-microcode 3.20201110.0ubuntu0.20.04.2`