# Laptop selectively will/will not wake up from suspend on Ubuntu 18.04.3

Tags: suspend, power-management

My laptop is an Acer predator.

When it goes to sleep mode, sometimes it does not wake up from sleep. By that, I mean the keyboard backlight comes on and the laptop's power light goes on as well and it looks like the laptop wakes up from sleep. But only screen is black so I can't see anything then I will be forced to hold down the power button for 5 secs..

It happens 1 out of 4 times when laptop goes to sleep. 
Could someone please help?

here is my var/log file i don't really understand were us the error, maybe someone could do please?...
 [log file](https://pastebin.com/hahjy4Wd)

Comment: Can you switch to terminal? login to confirm that maybe it's just your GUI/desktop that isn't waking... Do sysrq keys not work? (ie. kernel isn't responded when you kill gui, or cleanly force reboot/shutdown) is there a reason why you're using power to uncleanly shutdown?  I'd also avoid the emotion less we think it's an off-topic *rant in disguise* (https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Hi. thanks for your comment.. How do i switch to terminal? what are sysrq keys? and im using power buttong to force shut down because theres no other way. I can't see anything

Comment: I use ctrl+alt+F4 to switch to a text terminal (but because I find f4 & f5 easiest to type without looking).  The 'magic' sysrq keys aren't easy to remember, but a kernel specific keys that it'll respond to (unless it's crashed (kernel panic) or dead). I'll provide https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=617349 but note I usually use a search engine on a phone (magic sysrq is how wikipedia refers to it) where loads of combinations are available; alt+sysrq+REISUB being probably the most common

Comment: @guiverc thanks for being patient with me. SO i hit  ctrl + alt + f4 and went to command mode.  what do i do from there?

Comment: @guiverc i could log in and then i pressed alt and f7 to get back to gui mode

Comment: Beyond now being able to use a command to safely shutdown (`sudo shutdown -h now` ; the -h halts power, -r to reboot) we know the machine woke up, it's your GUI that doesn't.  I'm not a gnome user, nor have a box nearby to remind myself about what should be running; but I'd expect from terminal using `htop` or like tools to view system you'd see culprit that could be killed & thus cause session resume (even killing `gdm3` is better than forced shutdown; but I'd hope more precise than that).  I'd also check your extensions are for your GTK/gnome version (if you've added any)

Comment: Sorry i don't understand what do you mean. WHat should i do?

Comment: I've updated my answer based on your newly posted log file. Was laptop unplugged while it was suspended?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix  Hi. no my laptop is always plugged in. and if it gives a clue, it also doesnt send power to my mouse when it doesnt wanna wake up. i can usually tell when mouse LES also lights on, but when they don't screen doesnt either so i have to force shutdown by holding down Power  button

Comment: Every little clue helps.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix so yeh, it doesnt reboot, i have to force shutdown it. please let me know if i need to provide another log or anything.  I appreciate your time

Answer (score 4):

### February 18, 2020 update

Log file has been posted and when system suspends at 17:00 the next action is reboot at 20:00 (rather than resume):

```
Feb 17 16:25:30 neon-Predator-PH315-51 systemd-sleep[1430]: Suspending system...
Feb 17 16:25:30 neon-Predator-PH315-51 kernel: [32444.683507] PM: suspend entry (deep)
Feb 17 20:09:33 neon-Predator-PH315-51 systemd-modules-load[527]: Inserted module 'lp'
Feb 17 20:09:33 neon-Predator-PH315-51 kernel: [    0.000000] microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0xca, date = 2019-10-03
Feb 17 20:09:33 neon-Predator-PH315-51 kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 5.3.0-7625-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-052) (gcc version 7.4.0 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1)) #27~1576774585~18.04~c7868f8-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 19 20:37:47 UTC  (Ubuntu 5.3.0-7625.27~1576774585~18.04~c7868f8-generic 5.3.13)
Feb 17 20:09:33 neon-Predator-PH315-51 kernel: [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-7625-generic root=UUID=7db19782-809c-409f-9ac5-e76d1cf84345 ro quiet splash nouveau.runpm=0 vt.handoff=1
```

This is similar to:

- [Laptop reboots instead of resuming from systemd suspend when on battery power (suspending on AC power works)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/291546/laptop-reboots-instead-of-resuming-from-systemd-suspend-when-on-battery-power-s)
- [Dell XPS 15 (9550) rebooting after suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/871950/dell-xps-15-9550-rebooting-after-suspend)

---

You need to find the error message(s) that are occurring during resume from suspend. Once you know the error then you can fix it.

When your resume breaks and you restart your system open the terminal and type `gedit /var/log/syslog`. Then scroll to the section where the system suspended and resumed. For example, my system suspended at 5:52 am before going to work and resumed at 16:56 (4:56 pm) when returning home:

```
Jan 27 05:52:11 alien kernel: [1305328.821795] PM: suspend entry (deep)
Jan 27 05:52:11 alien kernel: [1305328.821797] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
Jan 27 05:52:13 alien acpid: client 1428[0:0] has disconnected
Jan 27 16:56:19 alien kernel: [1305331.145883] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.003 seconds) done.
Jan 27 16:56:19 alien kernel: [1305331.148954] OOM killer disabled.
Jan 27 16:56:19 alien kernel: [1305331.148955] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
```

Look through your own log file using this example until you find an error message and perform a google search on the error.

Use this same technique for all problems you encounter, not just suspend / resume errors.

Comment: hi ty for your info... another user suggested i update kernal... i did 5.5.3  but my virtualbox got issues so i installed 5.5 but with errors. now it keeps sayng... E:The package linux-headers-5.5.0-050500 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it....   could u help plz

Comment: Hey @winEunuuchs2Unix . I updated my post please have a look. I did what you suggested but theres liek so many lines i can't figire out whats gone wrong there, could you look at it please?  thanks

Comment: Hi @AnneWebster I found a link that seems promising: https://community.acer.com/en/discussion/577990/my-sf314-55-does-freeze-when-resuming-from-suspend-in-linux Can you run `dmesg | grep AE_ALREADY_EXISTS` and let me know if anything comes out? Also upgrading to kernel 5.5.3 might backfire. I use 4.14.170 (for 170 upgrades successfully so far). It is LTS (long term support) 5 year kernel. In the link just now user fixed their suspend/resume with 4.19 kernel which is also LTS.

Comment: Hi @Wineunuuchs2Unix that command did nothing, I mean didnt print out anything.  Upgrading karnel to 5.5.3 i think i can but it makes my virtualbox not working.   Ont thing else. i remember ive installed TLC. ( power saving software ) could it have anythign to do with it?  also my laptop is recently getting way to hot... anyway to see what causing it?  Thx

Comment: @AnneWebster If kernel 5.5.3 breaks things, go the other way and try 4.14 or 4.19. The power saving software is `tlp` and you [can turn it off](https://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-faq.html#stop-disable) or uninstall it with `sudo apt remove tlp`. Then reinstall it later after problems solved. The laptop skin temperature is usually caused by fans not running. You could boot with Windows to see how fast they usually run. Also in Windows check your BIOS firmware is up to date.

Answer (score 2):

There are couple things you could do.

If the only thing, that is missing is graphical interface you can open virtual console, login and start it from there:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> - will open first virtual console. Your GUI usually lives either in F1 or F7, but you can choose any of virtual desktops from F1 to F7

Once you open virtual console, you will see a full-screen terminal and you will be able to login. Once you have, you can start GUI by typing: `startx`

**Caution:** Do not try `sudo startx` - you will end up with more problems, than you have started with :)

If that helped and you now see your favorite desktop environment - good. If not - you need to keep looking on what is causing your problem and since this seems to be a phantom bug - it's not going to be trivial

**Updating kernel**

If you are not afraid of messing with your system - keep reading.
Often, when I buy a new hardware and it doesn't work as expected, the first thing I try before long and tedious investigation, is upgrading kernel to its latest version. It's not hard and it's likely, that newer kernel will have better support for newer hardware. This is especially true for laptops

In order to do that, go to:
https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/ and download latest and greatest kernel. You will find it in the bottom of the page. Today it is v5.5, whcih includes number of tweaks to power management and graphics. Avoid using those with rc in the name, like `v5.5-rc7` - this one still goes through testing.

Once you have located the latest kernel, check, that you are not already running one, by running `uname -sr`. This will show you the kernel you are running

If you are not running the latest version already - you may proceed with upgrading. Follow the link with the latest version. You will see the page with bunch of links to deb files. In 99% of the cases, you will need files from `Build for amd64 succeeded` section. These are the files you need to download (highlighted with red rectangles):

[image]

You can download them from your browser, save them in a new folder, navigate to that folder from command line and upgrade it from there. You could also run similar commands:

```
mkdir -p ~/Downloads/kernel
cd ~/Downloads/kernel
rm -rf ~/Downloads/kernel/*
wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.5/linux-headers-5.5.0-050500_5.5.0-050500.202001262030_all.deb
wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.5/linux-headers-5.5.0-050500-generic_5.5.0-050500.202001262030_amd64.deb
wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.5/linux-image-unsigned-5.5.0-050500-generic_5.5.0-050500.202001262030_amd64.deb
wget https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.5/linux-modules-5.5.0-050500-generic_5.5.0-050500.202001262030_amd64.deb
```

Now, all you need to do to install a new kernel is run:

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

Now you can reboot your machine and hopefully enjoy new kernel

Update kernel from GUI

If you want to update kernel, but you don't want to do it from command line for whatever reason, you could install and run UKUU (Ubuntu Kernel Upgrade Utility):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:teejee2008/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ukuu
sudo ukuu-gtk
```

Then you can upgrade the kernel from simple graphical user interface

If, for whatever reason, the kernel doesn't work for you - you can always restart your machine and change the kernel from grub menu. So, only delete old kernel, once you have confirmed, the new one works for you

I hope this guide helps

Comment: Hey. thanks for replying. i upgraded karnel by the GUI as u suggested to 5.3.3 hope i wont see the issue again. But now i have another Issue with Virtualbox and genymotion. Can you help me with that too plz?thx

Comment: The errors i get is...   ~$ sudo /usr/lib/virtualbox/vboxdrv.sh setup
vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
vboxdrv.sh: failed: Look at /var/log/vbox-setup.log to find out what went wrong.

Comment: I am glad it went good.

Can you please look if there are any errors in /var/log/vbox-setup.log? You may want to share the log file here or create a new question.

I highly suspect, that the problem you are running into is unsigned vbox kernel modules. For a quick fix, you may disable secure boot and see if that helps. Proper solution is described here: https://stegard.net/2016/10/virtualbox-secure-boot-ubuntu-fail/

Comment: Hi again. I have secure boot disabled in Bios.  Ive tried to find that log..but i couldnt find the /var  .. i wasnt able to locate that folder!  where is it?

Comment: I assume, you are using Nautilus to navigate your filesystem, which by default opens your home directory. Something like: /home/anne_webster. You may switch to /var directory by pressing Ctrl+L keys to open path bar, where you can type /var and hit Enter

Comment: I found  vbox-setup.log. there were a log1 log2 log3 and log4 too... But here is the first one.  the date is feb 15 but i am nto sure if all these lines in it are made in one day? cause there are alot of line. COuld you please have a look? https://controlc.com/03b47d46      Thanks